# Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window-error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have designed a ViewController "CommentsViewController" with xib and i am trying to present it on a popovercontroller over a grid cell when clicked on it...and below is my code

```
CommentsViewController *popOverVC=[[CommentsViewController alloc]init];
            popOverVC.delegate=self;
            popOverVC.commentBoxTextView.text=currentExternalGridCell.ratingValueLabel.text;
            popOverVC.contentSizeForViewInPopover=popOverVC.view.frame.size;
            UIPopoverController *popover =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popOverVC];
            popover.delegate=(id)self;
            popoverC=popover;




            [popover presentPopoverFromRect:currentExternalGridCell.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

but same gives an error..

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController _commonPresentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'
```

i have checked the value of self.view and currentexchangegrid cell both are not nil while i call the presentfromRect method...

**EDIT**

So i found a solution and was easy...

just check whether self.view.window!=nil before showing popover
ie,

```
if(self.view.window!=nil)
      [popover presentPopoverFromRect:currentExternalGridCell.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Where is this code called? If you call this in viewDidLoad the self.view is not yet assigned to the window.

Comment: @Cyprian not in viewDidLoad but i got it covered thanks for reply :-)